# Match returning null in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
var regEx = new RegExp("/[0-9]/");
var test = 'TREE'
alert(test.match(regEx));
```

or

```
var regEx = new RegExp("/[0-9]/");
var test = '1234'
alert(test.match(regEx));
```

Why do they return null?

Am i missing something here?

(Ok, the debate mentally drained me last night)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are using `new RegExp`, you don't need the delimiters (`/`).

```
var regEx = new RegExp("[0-9]");
var test = '1234'
alert(test.match(regEx));
```

You only need the slashes if you are using a regex literal (which I prefer using to `new RegExp`).

```
var regEx = /[0-9]/;
var test = '1234'
alert(test.match(regEx));
```

Answer (score 0):

To declare a RegExp:

```
var patt=new RegExp(pattern,modifiers);
```

or

```
var patt=/pattern/modifiers;
```

So try this:

```
var regEx = /[0-9]/g;
var test = '1234';
alert(test.match(regEx));
```